# How to apply filter on pivot table?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

Model of Category

```
public function lists(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Listing::class);
}
```

Model of Listing

```
public function categories(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Category::class)
        ->withPivot(['category_id','listing_id']); 
}
```

Controller: when I `dd` this query then I get all lists that is in listings table but I just want to get those lists whose have these categories.

```
if($request->categories){
    $var = $request->categories; // data in array 1,2,3
    $lists = Listing::with(['categories' => function ($query) use($var) {
        $query->whereIn('category_id',$var);
    }])->get();
    dd($lists);
```

Comment: This looks like a typo: `whereIn('category_id',['=',$var])`.  [The docs show the correct syntax](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries), so something like `whereIn('category_id', $var)` should be correct.

Comment: BTW: `belongsToMany(listing::class)` - apparently works, but the Model name should be correctly capitalised: `belongsToMany(Listing::class)`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic If you have any answer regarding this Question then it would be good instead of negative vote and correcting syntax that doesn't belongs to my question.

Comment: The code you posted had errors. I pointed out those errors and described how to fix them for you. If what you wrote here was not *actually* your code ... well, sorry, my mind reading does not seem to be working today.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is working perfect

```
 $state=$request->state;
    $type=$request->type;
    $categories=$request->categories;
    if(!$request->all()==null){
        $lists = Listing::when($state!=Null,function ($query) use ($state) {
            return $query->where('state', $state);})->
        when($type!=Null,function ($query) use ($type) {
            return $query->where('type', $type);});
       if(!$categories==null){
           foreach($categories as $var){
               $lists->whereHas('categories',function($q) use($var){
                   $q->where('category_id',$var);
               });
           }
       }
     $lists=$lists->get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give some id name to your table

```
<table id="userTable" style="display: table;" class="table table-responsive text-center table-striped table-hover">
```

and then use the following script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#userTable').DataTable( {
        scrollY:        "400px",
        scrollX:        true,
        scrollCollapse: true,
        paging:         true,
        columnDefs: [ {
            sortable: false,
            "class": "index",
            targets: 0
        } ],
        order: [[ 4, 'dsc' ]],
        fixedColumns: true
    } );
 
    table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
        table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
            cell.innerHTML = i+1;
        } );
    } ).draw();
} );


   </script>
```

now you must able to search, filter, reorder your table.